# Recently having trouble with socket.io connections via a Digitalocean load balancer (400 Error)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have a DO Load Balancer that has 4 servers behind it, I've been using socket.io with Sticky Sessions enabled in the Load Balancer settings and it had been working just fine for a while.

Recently clients have not been able to connect at all getting a 400 error immediately on connection. I haven't changed anything in the way I connect to the sockets at all. If I do require that the transport be 'websocket' only from the client it does connect successfully, but then I lose out on the polling backup (one of the main benefits of socket.io).

Also, connecting directly to one of the droplets works as expected, so the issue definitely stands with the Load Balancer.

Does anyone have any idea as to any kind of set up that should be in place for this to work with the DO Load Balancers? Anything that might have changed recently?

I'm running socket.io on a NodeJS server with Express if that helps at all.

Edit #1: Added a screenshot of the LB Settings

[image: DO LB Settings]

Comment: Can you show us your configs for the LBs?

Comment: @AvivLo Added a screenshot

Comment: Did you check the server logs for info? LBs might be sending malformed requests to the servers.

Comment: Yeah only thing I see is my app saying that a socket disconnected immediately as it connects, there's nothing in system logs or anything that I can find that syncs with the same time.

Comment: So there is no log whatsoever on both the LBs and the end servers?

Comment: I can't really see LB's logs since they're managed by DO, in terms of the end server I do get a 'socket disconnected' event without it even firing the 'connected' event, which is extremely weird. I've solved it temporarily by forcing my socket clients to use the websocket transport only, but that's obviously not the preferred method.

Comment: Why's websocket not the preferred method. Long polling, ajax multipart stream ... are all used only as a backup method by socket io

Comment: Websocket is preferred, but having these backups is one of major features of socket.io.

Comment: Probably the LBs blocked the rest of the methods? Did you write to DO and ask them about it ?

Comment: I did, it used to work just fine and then suddenly stopped working. So I sent them a support ticket and they said nothing changed on their end, so I have no idea what could have caused the issue.